# PHP is putting random strings into sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have spent all day trying to figure this out and I can't. I've literally tried everything(hence why the code is so dirty right now) to figure out why is the cause. This inserts into a SQL database but it's acting like it is counting the function and adding that to the beginning of the statement. here's my code

```
function countLoc($artist,$title,$title_number) {
$fileURL = get_bloginfo('url') . "/music/samples/" . $title_number . "/" . $artist . "/" . $title . "/" ;
$artistURL = rawurlencode($artist);
$titleURL = rawurlencode($title);
if ($handle = opendir("../music/samples/" . $title_number . "/" . $artist . "/" . $title )) {
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator('../music/samples/' . $title_number . "/" . $artist . "/" . $title );
    foreach($dir as $file ){ $y += ($file->isFile()) ? 1 : 0;};
    echo "a:".$y.":{i:0;";

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." ) {
            $baseURL = get_bloginfo('url') . "/music/samples/" . $title_number . "/" . $artistURL . "/" . $titleURL . "/" ;
            $fileURL = $baseURL . $entry;
            $trimmed = trim($entry, ".mp3");    
            $entry = rawurlencode($entry);
            $newBase = $baseURL . $entry;
            if (isset($x)){
                echo "i:" . $x . ";";
            };
            $countentry = strlen($trimmed);
            $countartist = strlen($artist); 
            $newBase = strlen($newBase);
            $x++;       
            echo "a:3:{s:24:\"releasetrack_track_title\";s:". $countentry .":\"". $trimmed ."\";s:24:\"releasetrack_artist_name\";s:". $countartist .":\"". $artist ."\";s:21:\"releasetrack_mp3_demo\";s:". $newBase .":\"". $baseURL . $entry ."\";}";
        }
    }
    echo "}";
    closedir($handle);
    } else {
      echo ""; 
    }}
```

The value in SQL comes to be wrapped in what appears to be a count of the number of characters in the full function - almost as if the whole thing was wrapped in strlen and I can't for the life of me figure out why(see below).

> s:1001"rest of the echo";

If I completely do away it the dir count then the strlen wrap is gone. Can anyone shed somelight?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but you're using `$y +=` and then checking if `$x` is set `if (isset($x))` yet, `$x` isn't defined anywhere; is `$x` coming in from elsewhere?

Comment: `$x` is just an increment integer i threw in there. the isset is checking to see if it's the first entry(there are usually about 10-20 in one dir) because the first entry can't have "i:" assigned. 
there could be a much simpler way of doing so, i'm still learning.

Comment: First off, `serialize()` is a thing; why are you manually trying to copy the output of it? http://us3.php.net/serialize

Comment: The provided code is not at fault. I faked your directory structure and it works fine. However, here's an improved version w/serialize: http://pastebin.com/EHEASFPU - if you post more code, we may be able to see where the s:1001 is coming from.

Comment: I did not know about `serialize()`, thank you for showing! 

I have no idea what it could be then. If I remove where it counts the dir then it's fine. This is in wordpress. I'm using the all import plugin which could overall be the problem but like i said if i remove the dir count then it's fine. here's what it's putting into SQL exactly. The `s:3081:"` at the beginning and `";` at the end make the whole statement break. 
http://pastebin.com/w0uj1x5d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My whole issue with this was something with the WP Import plugin. I updated it and it works perfectly fine now. Thanks guys for your help.